# How to access form fields in jquery using variable reference to the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Learning jquery, in chrome console created form:

```
var $form1 = $("<form/>", { id: 'form1' });
$div1.append($form1);
```

Then tried to access the fields during form submission:
This works:

```js
$('#form1').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#form1 input, #form1 select').each(function(index){
        var input = $(this);
        console.log('Type: ' + input.attr('type') + 'Name: ' + input.attr('name') + 'Value: ' + input.val());
    });
});
```

Output:
Type: textName: name1Value: hello world
Type: submitName: submit1Value: submit

But this does not:

```js
$($form1).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $($form1).each(function(index){
        var input = $(this);
        console.log('Type: ' + input.attr('type') + 'Name: ' + input.attr('name') + 'Value: ' + input.val());
    });
});
```

Output:
Type: undefinedName: undefinedValue:

How do I access the form fields using the variable $form1 instead of the actual element #form1?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: You are not eaching the inputs

Comment: How do I get access to the inputs? I tried $form1.children but that results in exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`children`](https://api.jquery.com/children/#children-selector) with selector to filter needed ones.

```js
var $div1 = $('body');
var $form1 = $("<form>", { id: 'form1' });
$div1.append($form1);

$form1.append('<input name="test" type="text"/> <input value="go" name="whattodo" type="submit" />');


$($form1).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $form1.children('input').each(function(index){
        var input = $(this);
        console.log('Type: ' + input.attr('type') + ' Name: ' + input.attr('name') + ' Value: ' + input.val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```